# having trouble installing openoffice on Fedora 13

Tags: installation, openoffice, fedora-13

I've followed all of these directions (twice now) for my x86 32-bit machine:
http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-openoffice-org-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

but I'm getting this error message after the last step:

```
[root@Moonface desktop-integration]# rpm -ivh *.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    openoffice.org3.2-suse-menus conflicts with openoffice.org3.2-freedesktop-menus-3.2-9502.noarch
    openoffice.org3.2-redhat-menus conflicts with openoffice.org3.2-freedesktop-menus-3.2-9502.noarch
    openoffice.org3.2-mandriva-menus conflicts with openoffice.org3.2-freedesktop-menus-3.2-9502.noarch
    mandrake-release is needed by openoffice.org3.2-mandriva-menus-3.2-9502.noarch
    /etc/SuSE-release is needed by openoffice.org3.2-suse-menus-3.2-9502.noarch
```

How do I resolve this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions:

If you don't mind having OpenOffice.org 3.2.0, just run

```
sudo yum search openoffice
sudo yum install openoffice.org-{writer,calc,impress}
```

Otherwise, if you don't already have any version of OpenOffice installed try this:

```
rm *suse-menus*
rm *mandriva-menus*
rm *freedesktop-menus*
rm *mandrake*
sudo rpm -ivh *.rpm
```

Comment: should I remove these openOffice files first with "yum remove openoffice.org*"?

Comment: Did you already install OpenOffice using Yum (or was it installed by default)?  What does rpm -qa "openoffice.org*" say?

Comment: i haven't installed it, but I downloaded the rpms (first step in the link i posted). The command you asked me to run returns nothing (back to prompt).

Comment: What about ls \*freedesktop\*?  I am assuming you are still in the OpenOffice.org download directory where you ran the rpm -ivh command the first time.

Comment: well, i ran the first "rpm..." command in this directory: "OOO320_m18_native_packed-1_en-US.9502"; I get this: ls: cannot access '*freedesktop'*: No such file or directory; but if I cd to RPMS/desktop-integration, I get this: "openoffice.org3.2-freedesktop-menus-3.2-9502.noarch.rpm

Comment: Maybe try this: rpm -ivh --aid openoffice.org-{writer,calc,impress}\*.

Comment: not sure what the "{}" means but: error: File not found by glob: openoffice.org-writer*
error: File not found by glob: openoffice.org-calc*
error: File not found by glob: openoffice.org-impress*

Comment: Sorry, add a star after org, i.e. "rpm -ivh --aid openoffice.org*-{writer,calc,impress}*rpm".

Comment: error: File not found by glob: openoffice.org*-writer*rpm
error: File not found by glob: openoffice.org*-calc*rpm
error: File not found by glob: openoffice.org*-impress*rpm

Comment: Let's go back to the start.  Why do you want to install it this way?  Why not just "yum search openoffice" then "yum install openoffice-exact-name-returned-by-search"?

Comment: well, i started trying that. yum search returned a sh*tpile of results. i'm kind of at a loss as to which one to install....

Comment: YES! ok, i blindly picked a "writer" and installed it. worked wonders.